# Collection of generic classes with inner generics

Tags: java, generics

With generics a class using inner generics can be declared:

```java
interface M1<T> {};

interface S1<T, M extends M1<T>> {}; // first generic interface is used as inner generics

class C1<T, M extends M1<T>, S extends S1<T,M>> { // second interface used
  void doSomething(Collection<S1> arg) { ... };
}
```

Instances of classes implementing S1 can be created. A collection with wildcards can also be declared:

```java
Collection<S1<?, ? extends M1<?>>> coll = Arrays.asList();
```

But unfortunately, here the demand on the generic type `T` is lost and replaced by wildcard.
Is there any way how to declare the collection keeping the restriction on the generic type of `M1`?

Comment: `Collection<?, ? extends M1<?>> coll = Arrays.asList();` wouldn't compile because `Collection` doesn't take two type variables. Please can you clarify the question?

Comment: "here the demand on the generic type T is lost" are you sure? I would expect it to infer two wildcard capture types constrained by the fact the second extends `M1<first>`. Something like `S1<?#1, ?#2 extends M1<?#1>>`. What is the thing you're trying to prevent but finding is allowed?

Comment: @AndyTurner at least I could create to `a = C1<String, ...>` and `b = C1<otherType, ...>` and put both into `coll = Array.asList(a,b)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying... is that what you want, or not what you want?

Comment: @AndyTurner I want to restrict the type of M1, something like `Collection<S1<T extends ?, ? extends M1<T>>>`

Comment: Can you [edit] to add a more concrete example of what you can currently do that you don't want to be able to do? I can't really follow your comments.